# Imageview rotation animation won't repeat on click

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, imageview

Whenever I press my flip button, my coin will only rotate on the first click. How do I make the animation work every time I click?

```
private fun flipCoin() {
    val flipButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.flip_button)
    flipButton.setOnClickListener {
        coinImage.animate().apply {
            rotationX(1800f)
            duration = 2000L
            start()
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because you set the rotation to 1800 on the first click and then set it again to 1800 on all subsequent clicks.

Try:

```
    flipButton.setOnClickListener {
        coinImage.animate().apply {
            rotationX(coinImage.getRotationX() + 1800f)
            duration = 2000L
            start()
        }
```